# Изменение вида CheckBox в Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

Сейчас мой CheckBox выглядит как обычный квадратик, хотелось бы исправить его например на круг, типа такого: [image: Нужный CheckBox]

Каким образом это можно сделать? Заранее спасибо

P.S. Разметка checkBox :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот небольшой пример:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkb"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
    android:scaleX="3"
    android:scaleY="3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />
```

создайте новый xml файл в папке drawable с названием custom_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

Comment: спасибо, вроде получилось

Comment: а state_checked="false" ?